# Disable GestureDetector in Activity

Tags: android, gestures

In my app, I have an activity that uses onTouchEvent() to calculate screen input. But on some phones, eg. Samsung Galaxy S4 the event is aborted in favor of GestureDetector, with the log message:

```
GestureDetector(23138): [Surface touch Event] Palm swipe start, x:565.0 m:450.0 s:54.0 TILT_TO_ZOOM_XVAR: 180.0
```

The problem disappears when the user turns Movements and Gestures off in the Android Phone Settings menu, but this is to hard to find to be convenient.

How can I disable this, without forcing the user to exit the app or change the phone settings?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works, but my first idea is requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent() may help you ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29 ).

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
       viewPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this seems to have no effect on the GesureDetector, and the error persists. There seems to be some kind of separate process running, not connected to my activity? Very annoying!